# Partial Overlap of an Object in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

[image: Example image]

The black part of this image is the outline of the State of Georgia, and the orange part is a line that is meant to have the effect of orbiting the state.

I would like to make this illusion, but I don't know how to get the tail end that is meant to look like it is going behind the black outline of the State.

What do I do, because playing around in Illustrator CS6, I can only get the entire orbital behind the state, not just the two tail ends.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert the orange stroke to outline.
2. Copy the black shape
3. Click on the orange shape and paste the black shape in Front (Control F)
4. Select the new black shape and the orange shape and use the pathfinder Divide tool to divide the shapes
5. Cut the orange part that should be in front of the black shape
6. Delete any duplicate black, orange and transparent shapes that appeared as a result of Divide tool
7. Paste in Front (Control F)

This should do it.

If you want to give the orange shape a little depth use a gradient fill and make the part that comes out underneath the black shape a bit darker.